# GStreamer Android Tutorials crashing

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am able to build and launch all 5 of the Android GStreamer tutorials that are included with `gstreamer-sdk-android-arm-debug-2013.6`. But tutorials 3-5 crash in the same way shortly after launch. I have tried to run on a new Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2 and also a Rockchip Tronsmart Orion R28. Both devices are running Android 4.4.2 (API 19). The relevant portions of the LOGCAT follows:

```
I/GStreamer﹕ Gst initialized. Restoring state, playing:false
D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 8 (SIGFPE) at 0x00002782 (code=-6), thread 10140 (eglglessink-ren)

I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'rockchip/rk3288/rk3288:4.4.2/KOT49H/eng.sz.20140926.095851:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 10114, tid: 10140, name: eglglessink-ren  >>> com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3 <<<
I/DEBUG﹕ signal 8 (SIGFPE), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr 00002782
I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 0000279c  r2 00000008  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000008  r5 00000002  r6 0000279c  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG﹕ r8 00003092  r9 78032000  sl 7812fc94  fp 4013e2ec
I/DEBUG﹕ ip 7871da90  sp 7812fbe0  lr 4010509d  pc 40114048  cpsr 000e0010
I/DEBUG﹕ d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d4  43f5800000000000  d5  3f80000043b84000
I/DEBUG﹕ d6  0000000000000000  d7  421d7af6461c4000
I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000014
I/DEBUG﹕ d18 000000007871dea0  d19 00000000002d8800
I/DEBUG﹕ d20 0000000000000000  d21 00000000002d8800
I/DEBUG﹕ d22 0000000000003800  d23 0000000000003800
I/DEBUG﹕ d24 0000000000000018  d25 0000000000000040
I/DEBUG﹕ d26 0000000000000028  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG﹕ d30 3fe0000000000000  d31 3f4de16b9c24a98f
I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000010
I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00022048  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00013099  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 000132ad  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0003b9c0  /system/lib/libc.so (__aeabi_idiv0+8)
I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 0019a224  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 003cf998  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so (eglQuerySurface+1216)
I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0000f5cd  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglQuerySurface+72)
I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 001a2f75  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_egl_adaptation_query_par+52)
I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 001a2229  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so (gst_egl_adaptation_init_egl_surface+84)
I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 001a0577  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 0052e59b  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 0000d228  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG﹕ #12  pc 0000d3c0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fba0  403a7e04  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fba4  784d1358  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fba8  7671e805  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbac  7666cd0f  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbb0  00000003
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbb4  76b804a0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbb8  00000004
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbbc  76b804a0  [anon:libc_malloc]
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbc0  0000000c
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbc4  403a2004  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbc8  401401c0
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbcc  7666cd0f  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-    1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbd0  7671e805  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-   1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbd4  7812fc2c  [stack:10140]
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbd8  7671e7be  /data/app-lib/com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_3-    1/libgstreamer_android.so
I/DEBUG﹕ 7812fbdc  7812fc34  [stack:10140]
```

Comment: Previously I have the same issue. It's gone after migration to GStreamer 1.0

Comment: with both gst-0.1 and gst-1.0 I am having the issue that `#include <gst/gst.h>` fails. Did you have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the latest version from: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.4.4/

GStreamer 0.10 is no longer maintained, and the stuff from gstreamer.com has nothing to do with the GStreamer project.

If the problem still exists, please report a bug at http://bugzilla.gnome.org against GStreamer. Crashes are something to report in GStreamer's bug tracker, not on stackoverflow where they just get lost.

Comment: I've downloaded the new version, but it doesn't contain the sample applications and it isn't obvious how link the samples that came with the old version with the new sdk.

Comment: You can find the same tutorials ported to the new version here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - that got me a lot further along. It is now failing trying to compile Tutorial5.java: package org.freedesktop.gstreamer does not exist. I have GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT and GSTREAMER_ROOT set to mypath/gstreamer-1.0-android-arm-debug-1.4.4. Are there others that need to be set?

Comment: I got it working. I found that the ndk-build step copies GStreamer.java to jni/src. I just needed to add the following line to `sourceSets.main` in the apps build.gradle file: `java.srcDirs += 'src/main/jni/src'`